# solving for lagrange multiplier in function of distribution

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

This is the first time I have encountered a functional derivative. My background is not in Physics so this functional derivative concept is quite perplexing to me.

I have a function of distribution as follows:

$$L(q(z)) = \int q(z) E[log(p(z|x)] dq(z) - \int q(z) (log q(z)) dq(z) + \lambda(1- \int q(z) dq(z)) $$

There is a langrange multiplier because I want to force $\int q(z) dq(z) = 1$.
From my understanding, if I treat $q(z)$ as a variable, the above expression should be:

$$L'(q(z)) = E[log(p(z|x)] - log(q(z)) - \lambda $$

I don't feel good about my derivation. I look up online on functional calculus and it does not mention about infinite integral. Leibniz integral rule does not seem to be applicable here. Can anyone point out how to take a derivative of the above expression?

The solution should be:

$$L'(q(z)) = E[log(p(z|x)] - log(q(z)) - 1$$

I have no clue how did the author derive the $\lambda$ and somehow knows that it is equal to 1.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this from a textbook?

Comment: It is from the lecture slide. Blei, David M. "Variational Inference." Lecture from Princeton, https://www. cs. princeton. edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/variational-inference-i. pdf (2011).
APA

Comment: [PDF link here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/variational-inference-i.pdf).